# How to mask the data after one-hot encoding in keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, masking, one-hot-encoding

Suppose we have raw data like this:

```
raw_inputs = [
    [711, 7, 632, 71],
    [73, 8, 3215, 55, 927],
    [83, 91, 1, 645, 1253, 927],
]
```

After padding:

```
padded_inputs = tf.keras.preprocessing.sequence.pad_sequences(
    raw_inputs, padding="post")
```

The result is

```
[[ 711    7  632   71    0    0]
 [  73    8 3215   55  927    0]
 [  83   91    1  645 1253  927]]
```

If I use **Masking** layer for the above data, it is a correct mask. But if I use one-hot encoding first, and transform the above data into a three-dimensional tensor. There are some zeros which I don't want to mask. But the masking layer will treat the zero values equally. Can I create a mask array by myself instead of detecting zeros directly?

BTW: in keras, the padding element zero will not be a zero vector after one-hot encoding. How can I do? Should I care about that?